# Jpa сущность сохранилась в таблицах не так как ожидал?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa

У меня есть spring-приложение с использованием oracle11g+jpa

Две таблицы

```
Customer(с информацией о потребителе)
objectId(ключ)      sourceId
111-222             source0
333-333             source11


и таблица с информацией об устройствах
id(ключ)        sourceId         deviceName
```

Между таблицами при создании связи нет, просто есть две отдельные таблицы без внешних ключей.

Мои Jpa сущности выглядят так

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Device")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Device {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "sourceId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "sourceId")
    private String sourceId;

    @Column(name = "deviceName")
    private String deviceName;
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    private String objectId;

    @Column(name = "sourceId")
    private String sourceId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sourceId")
    private List<Device> deviceList;
}
```

Я использую CrudRepository от spring и сейчас это работает так - сохраняю объект вроде

Customer{
  objectId:null,
  sourceId:26,
  deviceList: {
           {id:null, sourceId:26, deviceName: iphone}
  }
}

А по факту, в базу сохранилось так

```
Сustomer
objectId(ключ)      sourceId
111-222             26


Device
id        sourceId      deviceName
as-sa     111-222       iphone
```

А требуется, чтобы в таблице Device в столбце sourceId было 26, а не значение objectId.
Что тут нужно поправить?

Comment: Уберите из `Device` поле `sourceId`

Comment: @Serodv к сожалению не помогло. По прежнему в столбце sourceId в Device пишется objectId из Customer(ожидаю записать не уникальное поле sourceId)

Comment: Хотя intelij idea и подсказывает что внутри Device подразумевается @Column(name="sourceId") @JoinColumn(name="sourceId")
При создании таблиц связь между ними не создавалась